# What does "Leibniz" mean as a step in a proof?

Tags: terminology, proof-explanation

What does the step annotated "{ Leibniz }" refer to in the following proof from [this paper](http://www.cs.nott.ac.uk/~psztxa/publ/cmcs01.pdf)? The logic of the step in the proof is clear, I just don't understand the reference.
[image: proof]

Comment: Probably this, although I find this usage very strange: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_of_indiscernibles

Comment: I agree: It's not _really_ a case of identity of indiscernibles.  But if that's not what was meant, then I'm at a loss.  Sometimes "Leibniz rule" means the product rule for differentiation, but that's not what it means this time. $\qquad$

Comment: They mean the identify of indiscernibles as per Quiacho Yuan's link, in the sense that the relation $g(x) = g(y)$  cannot distinguish the objects $f\,a$ and $f\,a'$ that have just been shown to be equal. I too find this strange - I would just have written "{ Equality laws }". The paper you quote comes from a computer science community with some good ideas about computer science but some occasionally odd-seeming ways of talking about mathematics and mathematical logic. Don't judge it too harshly.

Comment: Thanks for the above comments, that makes sense. Also noticed that in another version of the same paper, the term "substitutivity" is used instead (http://www.cs.nott.ac.uk/~pszgmh/when.pdf)